# Wordpress not reflecting changed of the database

Tags: php, database, mysql, migration

my problems started when I moved my website to another folder (from /dev/ to /).
I have gone through the whole database in order to change all the hardcoded /dev/ into / but I still notice that wordpress, somehow, still uses the old values.

Basically the website uses information that are not there anymore.
I checked my own and the server cache and they all seem to be clean (the server doesn't even seem to have that feature on).

So, I am pretty much lost...

**FIXED:** The problem was related to the revision number of every information. Having changed some values directly from the DB but not the revision number, wordpress would reject the change and show nothing (as there were no previous versions).

I just entered all the missing information by hand and it worked.

Basically, don't mess with the DB. Wordpress doesn't forgive!

Comment: You've missed something. Did you go through the DB by hand? Or use a tool? Is your site URL hard-coded into `wp-config.php`?

Comment: I went through by hand (using the Search function and replacing stuff). I think the issue was related to revision numbers and such.

Comment: "was related to"? Is it fixed?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed :)

Comment: Would you post the fix in an "answer" box below, so as to help other people with similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to try using this:

http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

As @s_ha_dum has said, it looks like you've missed something. The above script automates the process of updating all URL references within the database when changing folder/URL and is much quicker and easier.

You've probably missed some entries as some references to the URL are stored as serialized data in the database...

Don't forget to check the settings for the site URL in the wp-config.php file too...